# AWS AppSync WebUI very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

We have a AWS AppSync with a rather large schema running (currently roughly 2k lines) and in the browser (Chrome) the **schema view** loads really slow

Time to first byte etc is all good, the page is rendered in less than a second but it takes minutes until the schema text-field or the resolvers drop-down is responsive.

Anybody notices similar patterns?
Anybody knows an easy workaround?
(Note: we would love to keep appsync, as it is a great tool)

Comment: I've complained about this on AWS forums almost a year ago. Doesn't look like a priority to them. Would be nice if there was a check box (check off by default) that you can specify if you want schema inspection. So annoying when you just want to add a field or tweak a resolver and it takes several minutes before you can even scroll the editor...

Answer (score 2):

It is because the resolver box is loading far too much information. Type anything into the filter for the resolvers and after a few seconds it will become responsive.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to say that is the best solution I've seen to work quickly with Appsync Console. Thanks for the tips !